# C++ Convert int to *LONG

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, int, type-conversion, long-integer

I have the following code:

```
STDMETHODIMP CWrapper::openPort(LONG* m_OpenPortResult)
{
    string str("test");
    const char * c = str.c_str();

    m_OpenPortResult=Open(c); //this does not work because "Open" returns an int

    return S_OK;
}

int Open(const char* uKey)
{

}
```

I can not convert "int" to "LONG*".
The compiler tells me "'int' can't be converted to 'LONG *'.

I also tried using INT* instead of LONG*, but that also gave me an error.

Can somebody tell me how I can convert int to LONG* or INT*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything.  `LONG*` is a pointer to a `LONG`, and you can assign an `int` to a `LONG`.  Simply dereference the pointer so you can then assign it:

```
*m_OpenPortResult = Open(c); // <-- note the *
```

Or safer:

```
if (!m_OpenPortResult) return E_POINTER;
*m_OpenPortResult) = Open(c);
```

Or even:

```
LONG ret = Open(c);
if (m_OpenPortResult) *m_OpenPortResult = ret;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to dereference the pointer you pass to `openPort` to make it work.

```
*m_OpenPortResult = Open(c);
```

This way you write to the address where `m_OpenPortResult` actually points to. This is what you want.
You may also want to read something about references in C++. If you are able to (in form of you are the developer of the `openPort`-function) modify the function, you might use

```
STDMETHODIMP CWrapper::openPort(LONG &m_OpenPortResult)
{
    // code...
    m_OpenPortResult = Open(c);
    return S_OK;
}
```

The appropriate call would look like

```
LONG yourResult;
wrapperInstance.openPort(yourResult); // without & before!
```

This might fit your needs better since references have several advantages and should be used when there is no explicit reason to use pointers.